# Matplotlib scatter plot with two colors for only two series in dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe with two series and no categories. I want to plot the scatter-plot for x and y with different colors.

I tried `plt.scatter(obs_flow, sim_flow,c=('red','blue'), alpha=0.3)` but gave an error :

`ValueError: 'c' argument has 2 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 3954.`

How do I define the colors in this case when no category is available? Here's how my dataframe looks like:
[image].

EDIT :
The plot without any color argument passed is looking like this:
[image]

Can we have different colors for observed and simulated points?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to achieve: you have your observation data on your x-axis and the simulated data an your y-axis. What is your second series? Are you trying to plot both, observations and simulation results, against the date?

Comment: Yes, I am plotting observed data on x axis and simulated on y. The date is not applicable here. I have attached the plot for your reference. I simply want different colors for observed and simulated points,if that's possible.

Comment: There are no more different points: you have data with two dimensions (observed and simulated) and plot them in a two-dimensional space where x represents the value of _observed_ and y the value of _simulated_. What should a third dimension (colour) represent? Take a look at the example plot you provided: what colour should the value at (1750, 300) have and based on what feature?

Comment: So, basically there's no option other than creating a third series containing some sort of categories. Thank you.